# Adding global keybinding for JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I have:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        JButton c = new JButton();
        c.setText(Integer.toString(i));
        ActionListener l = new NumericButtonListener(i);
        c.addActionListener(l);
        buttonGrid.add(c); }
```

So basically, some code that creates a grid of numbers. How can I map my pane to allow hitting the appropriate number and trigger my NumericButtonListener?

Comment: implement the ActionListener. later you check using getActionCommand method in actionPerformed method.

Comment: @subash Sorry, I don't follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use `keyBindings` and assign one common `Action` for the specific key.
2. Make use of button's [`doClick()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29) function to generate an Action event and listens to it. You will need to invoke this function on the specific button to which mapped key is pressed. For example:

   ```
   Action generateClick = new AbstractAction() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         JButton butt = (JButton) e.getSource();
         butt.doClick();
     }
    };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use keyBinding for each button. See [tutorial for KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

For example add next code in creation:

```
c.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(Integer.toString(i)), "doSomething");
c.getActionMap ().put("doSomething", new AbstractAction() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println(c.getText());
      }  
});
```